# how to insert my custom template file in list page using xml without using getChild html and not rewrite list.phtml

Tags: magento

This is how i tried. bud didn't get answer. what my template will do is each product image will have a like button. i have done with view.phtml but not in list.phtml. Pls friends broadcast your knowledge.

```
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="productlike/most" name="productlike" before="-">
            <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="section_1/group_1/enabled"><template>productlike/like.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing.  If you're trying to insert the `productlike` block into the `list.phtml` file, you MUST rewrite the `list.phtml` and use `$this->getChildHtml('productlike');` to call the block in the template.  The default `list.phtml` file does not call `productlike` so it won't display.

Comment: First of all thank you for your response Mr. Axel.(Smiling). Yeah what you understood is correct. But I need to insert my block into list.phtml without getChildHtml(), and rewrite technique. What about method="insert" in layout xml file.

Comment: http://www.atwix.com/magento/insert-blocks/